# Error message box width too small

Tags: feature-request, design, error-message

I think the below error message box could have its width increased. Not sure if other errors suffer from the new compact CSS.

[image: Error message box a bit small]

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's a request to change the design of error messages. (which got +1 from me :))

Answer (score 5):

That error message is pretty cramped, but a lot of it is because of the padding to the right (50 pixels for a box nearly 130 pixels wide).

[image]

In addition to making the message wider, it would be nice if the padding to the right was made uniform with the padding on the left, eg:

[image]

The example above is just the standard error message, with these differences:

- padding on right matches padding on left (15px),
- increased width
- close button has slight margin to left and bottom

Answer (score 0):

**Suggested Fix**

The following `div` contains the error message markup.

```
<div class="error-popup error-popup-alert error-popup-dismissable" 
     style="position: absolute; display: block;">
```

Based on my tests, when using a percentage for the width, the `div` inherits the width from the `<table>` containing the comments. Therefore, setting a width of 50% works well. The error message will always be half the width of the table containing the comments.

I set the width to 50% using Chrome. It's not immediately clear which class would need to be set: `error-popup`, `error-popup-alert`, or `error-popup-dismissable`.

[image: Example fix]

Also, the inner `div` containing the actual error message contains an inline style padding that might not be need. It's tough to say since I'm not sure where else this styling may be used.

```
<div class="error-message" style="padding-right: 50px;">
```